# Issue in XmlHttpRequest .send

Tags: javascript

I tried to do `XmlHttpRequest.send` request and it failed.

I got error message  -

```
MLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

I don't have a lot of knowledge in `XmlHttpRequest`.

I tried to ran it on chrome and firefox

this is how I open the connection

```
         this.xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", url, isAsync );
```

send

```
         this.xmlHttpRequest.send( request.getData() );
```

what could be the problem?and how I can solve this issue ?

Comment: Sample code? Which browser? jsFiddle? Please.

Comment: I agree with Tomasz... however, check if you have the right values in the *open* function and then check if request.getData() contain some payload. Any way, a sample code will help others to help you.

Comment: I checked it and it opened the connection and it failed in the send , I have some payload context but it still failed.Maybe it is issue of authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the correct protocol? If it requires SSL and your url is http:// then you may receive a 101 status code.

http://100pulse.com/http-statuscode/101.jsp